# How to merge rows based on the maximum number of non null values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Consider the following mysql table

**T**

```
 c1   c2   c3   c4
 -------------------
 X    NULL NULL NULL
 w    NULL NULL NULL 
 NULL y    NULL NULL 
 NULL Z    NULL NULL 
 NULL NULL P    NULL 
 NULL NULL NULL A 
 NULL NULL Q    NULL 
 NULL NULL NULL B 
 NULL NULL NULL C
```

Now I want output like this

```
 c1   c2   c3   c4
 -------------------
 x    Y    P    A
 w    z    Q    B
 NULL NULL NULL C
```

As you can see that the output is displayed based on the maximum number of non-null values across the columns.

Can anybody help me how to achieve this using mysql.

**UPDATE**

Only one column value in the row will always be not null and rest of three columns will always be null.

Comment: If only 1 column will be populated, then it looks like bad design. You can add 2 column, first will contain the value what you've entered as column name currently, and second column will contain the value.

Comment: @Nimesh This is not a designed table but the output generated from pivot table query read about it here than you will understand the purpose, refer http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Comment: I know what a pivot table is and how it works, you mentioned that as a table so I added the suggestion. Is that was the output then you should've mentioned accordingly and provided the code. Btw, did you use `coalesce` as mentioned in step 4 of the article to get rid of the nulls?

Comment: @Nimesh sorry for that but coalesce will not help me because here data is not of the type int or number, also i didn't require an aggregate functions to be performed on the columns as you can see from expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query please:

```
SELECT 
MAX(CASE WHEN t.colName = 'C1' THEN t.f ELSE NULL END ) AS 'C1',
MAX(CASE WHEN t.colName = 'C2' THEN t.f ELSE NULL END ) AS 'C2',
MAX(CASE WHEN t.colName = 'C3' THEN t.f ELSE NULL END ) AS 'C3',
MAX(CASE WHEN t.colName = 'C4' THEN t.f ELSE NULL END ) AS 'C4'
FROM 
(
    SELECT c2 AS f,
      'C2' AS colName,
      @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 row_number
    FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
    WHERE c2 IS NOT NULL

    UNION 

    SELECT c1,
      'C1' AS colName,
      @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 row_number
    FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn1 := 0) var
    WHERE c1 IS NOT NULL

    UNION

    SELECT 
      c4,
      'C4' AS colName,
      @rn4 := @rn4 + 1 row_number
    FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn4 := 0) var
    WHERE c4 IS NOT NULL

    UNION

    SELECT 
      c3,
      'C3' AS colName,
      @rn3 := @rn3 + 1 row_number
    FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn3 := 0) var
    WHERE c3 IS NOT NULL 
) t
GROUP BY t.row_number;
```

---

Please check the [**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b385/1/0)

**Explanation:**

Consider one of the INNER queries:

Here's one:

```
SELECT c2 AS f,
'C2' AS colName,
@rn2 := @rn2 + 1 row_number
FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
WHERE c2 IS NOT NULL;
```

**Output for Column C2:**

```
f   colName   row_number
y     C2          1
z     C2          2
```

Actually Each of the above inner query will give an alike output structure:

**Output for Column C1:**

```
f  colName   row_number 
x    C1        1
w    C1        2
```

**Output for Column C3:**

```
f  colName   row_number 
p    C3         1
Q    C3         2
```

**Output for Column C4:**

```
f   colName   row_number
A     C4         1
B     C4         2
C     C4         3
```

Now if you `UNION` them all you will get an output structure like below:

```
f   colName   row_number
y     C2         1
z     C2         2
x     C1         1
w     C1         2
A     C4         1
B     C4         2
C     C4         3
p     C3         1
Q     C3         2
```

Look, if I didn't use the column name column in each of the inner query then there would be now way to know which value belongs to which column.

Now from the above final output structure if you use `pivoting` then you can easily derive the expected output.

Comment: You CODE appears to work pefectly just explain me what does the following code does `SELECT c2 AS f,
'C2' AS colName,
@rn2 := @rn2 + 1 row_number
FROM mergetable,(SELECT @rn2 := 0) var
WHERE c2 IS NOT NULL`
I am still new to advance sql

Comment: Please check now. I've added explanation. @geeksal

Comment: thanks I understand it some how partially, but i will recommend a more clear explanation or some tutorial link on the same. Any ways Accepted your answer but still trying to learn the concept.  :)